# simple posts list with buttons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Please help me to understand one dumb thing.
In one hand I have user with many posts, in other hand I have list with posts (every post have button) in view. On button I need to call custom method on current post with parameters. How to do this?

Comment: Are you want to call javascript method or controller action through ajax ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
link_to 'Submit', model_path(:query => "value"), :remote => true, :method => :post
```